# How can I say "we met at x event" politely in an email?

Tags: keigo

I'm trying to email someone pretty high up in a company and want him to remember who I am.

**Edit:** I met him briefly at a trade show. We exchanged business cards and spoke for less than five minutes.

Should I use:

お目にかかりました

or, what I think is probably more appropriate, an expression using some kind of 授受表現 like

お目にかからせていただきました

お会いしていただきました

お会いさせていただきました

or something similar? I have a feeling there's a kanji word for this kind of situation, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Have you spoken with that person, or just saw that person? It depends on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best choice would be:

> ({先日 / [date] に} [event]で) お目にかかりました

I think this would also work:

> ご挨拶させていただきました

These sound a bit awkward to me:

> - お目にかからせていただきました
> - お会いしていただきました
> - お会いさせていただきました

Comment: @sawa-san, Wow thank you for editing!

Answer (score 1):

if you really 'met' him, like greeting and not just saw him from far away you could say something like:

```
ご挨拶させて頂きました。
ご紹介させて頂きました。
```

etc.

Comment: Note: not お挨拶, but ご挨拶 basically ご is used for kanji-characters (jukugo), and お is used more hiragana characters. お会い: ok, ご会い: ng, but お挨拶: ng, ご挨拶: ok

Comment: We don't say 「お」挨拶...  We'd say ご挨拶させていただきました... I think ご紹介させていただきました means "I introduced (someone) to you". (I think the を is normally left out)